# How to create required gpio pin mapping in uboot

Tags: gpio, u-boot

I'm trying to add a new the gpio controller driver in u-boot. I've actually added and enabled the driver but it needs a small fix and I'm not able to figure out how to handle this. I'm somewhat new to the u-boot and gpio frameworks.

My problem is, there are two gpio controllers i.e My dts file looks like the below

```
gpio1:gpio@505050505 {
/* this bank has hw pins 0 - 29 */
ngpio = 30;
};

gpio0:gpio@a0a0a0a0 {
/* this bank has hw pins 0 - 19*/
ngpio = 20;
};
```

In the driver probe function, i see that gpio1 is probed first and then the gpio0 is probed. Due to this probe(dt parsing) order, the pin mapping created is as shown below

```
pin 0 - 29 mapped to gpio1 hw pins 0 - 29 and
Pin 30 - 49 mapped to gpio0 hw pins 0 - 19
```

but my requirement is to have it reversed, i.e

```
pin 0 - 19 mapped to gpio0 hw pins 0 - 19 and
pin 20 - 49 mapped to gpio1 hw pins 0 - 29
```

and i can't change the dt node entry order(req from client).
I've already looked into aliases section where the bus nos. are assigned. I wanted to know if there is any field in dt node which determines the order or anything in uboot gpio framework which can determine the pin mapping.